# how to show content of doc file having text and images in a web page using php

Tags: php, file-io

I have uploaded the doc files in my server and now i have to show the content of doc files in web page. Now i am not getting any way to show that content as doc may contain images, tables,  and other type of texts.

I tried to work with file_get_contents and then using headers but not possible in all ways.

Comment: Clearing the problem. Suppose i have an article with images and other things in a doc file. Now i have uploaded that article in server. Now I have to show only first 300 characters in one article listing page and on read more click i have to show full article description.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, .doc/.docx file is not a text file. I don't think with file_get_contents you shall get any normal text character as output.

You can do two things:

> 1. Convert the doc/docx to pdf and show in your web page [Try: OfficeToPdf]
> 2. Convert the doc/docx to html compatible format using library [Try: PhpWord]

**Links**
PhpWord: http://phpword.codeplex.com/
OfficeToPdf: http://officetopdf.codeplex.com/

The libraries I mentioned are for example, there are a plenty of libraries available for free. Just Google to get them. Good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

Docx is a zipped file format, so you can't get any information with file_get_contents.

Doc is not zipped, so you will directly get all information in XML format when opening with file_get_contents.

If you want to convert the files for a webviewing, you could use one of the libraries mentioned by @programmer

PhpWord: http://phpword.codeplex.com/

OfficeToPdf: http://officetopdf.codeplex.com/

Comment: are you understanding what i want to do here. I have just doc files uploaded in server, they can contain images and other things. Now how will i get the content of that doc as its in the document and show in a webpage.